# $6x^2-5xy-6y^2$ reducible over $\mathbb Z$

Tags: quadratic-forms

Why is $f = 6x^2 -5xy -6y^2$ reducible over $\mathbb Z$?

And: Why is every quadratic form with discriminant $0$ properly equivalent to a unique form $f=ax^2$?

Comment: What do you mean by "why is it it reducible". It obviously factors $(3x+2y)(2x-3y)$, What else is there to say? If you ask why $ax^2+bxy+c^2$ factors as $a(x+\frac{b}{2a})^2$ if $b^2=4ac$. Well again, what do you mean by "why"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set $t=\frac xy$ and dehomogeneise $f$:

$f(x,y)=y^2(6t^2-5t+6)$.

Now the single variable $6t^2-5t+6$ has rational roots $-2/3$ and $3/2$, whent the factorisation
$$6t^2-5t+6=(3t+2)(2t-3),$$
and finally, rehomogeneising,
$$f(x,y)=y(3t+2)(2t-3)=(3ty+2y)(2ty-3y)=(3x+2y)(2x-3y).$$